# Do I use „by” or ”on” in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

By his return to the States,John had travelled a lot. OR : On his return to the States,John had travelled a lot. which is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sound a bit forced.

Although "On his return" is slightly more correct, the second half of the sentence doesn't quite fit. "On his return" expresses something that happened **during** the return journey, but you are trying to express that he travelled a lot **before** he returned home.

The best suggestion I can come up with is

> By the time he returned to the States, John had travelled a lot.

However, this would also fit:

> On his return to the States, John realized he had travelled a lot.

Because John had this realization (about his recent past, in which he travelled a lot) **during** the return journey.